# Installing CDH using Cloudera Manager: No such file or directory

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

Installing using CM and successfully download and distribute all parcels.

However, all agents do not decompress parcels when distribution is 100% finished. Checking the log, it says:

```
[21/Nov/2018 09:53:04 +0000] 30292 MainThread parcel       INFO     Executing command ['chown', 'root:yarn', u'/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.0.1-1.cdh6.0.1.p0.590678/lib/hadoop-yarn/bin/container-executor']
[21/Nov/2018 09:53:04 +0000] 30292 MainThread parcel       INFO     chmod: /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.0.1-1.cdh6.0.1.p0.590678/lib/hadoop-yarn/bin/container-executor 6050
[21/Nov/2018 09:53:04 +0000] 30292 MainThread parcel       INFO     Executing command ['chmod', '6050', u'/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.0.1-1.cdh6.0.1.p0.590678/lib/hadoop-yarn/bin/container-executor']
[21/Nov/2018 09:53:04 +0000] 30292 MainThread parcel       ERROR    Error while attempting to modify permissions of file '/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.0.1-1.cdh6.0.1.p0.590678/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/sbin/Linux/task-controller'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/cloudera/cm-agent/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cmf/parcel.py", line 520, in ensure_permissions
    file = cmf.util.validate_and_open_fd(path, self.get_parcel_home(parcel))
  File "/opt/cloudera/cm-agent/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cmf/util/__init__.py", line 358, in validate_and_open_fd
    fd = os.open(path, flags)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.0.1-1.cdh6.0.1.p0.590678/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/sbin/Linux/task-controller'
[21/Nov/2018 09:54:04 +0000] 30292 MainThread heartbeat_tracker INFO     HB stats (seconds): num:40 LIFE_MIN:0.01 min:0.01 mean:0.01 max:0.01 LIFE_MAX:0.05
[21/Nov/2018 10:04:04 +0000] 30292 MainThread heartbeat_tracker INFO     HB stats (seconds): num:40 LIFE_MIN:0.01 min:0.01 mean:0.01 max:0.01 LIFE_MAX:0.05
```

Why the path `'/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.0.1-1.cdh6.0.1.p0.590678/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/sbin/Linux/task-controller'` is missing and how to address this issue?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exactly same trouble and could not solve it after a lot of waste of time.  I finally ended up with installing via "package" method instead of "parcel" method.